# Java Cipher.getInstance() shows java.lang.NoSuchFieldError :address in solaris

Tags: java, encryption, aes, java-security

my Encryptor code:

```
public class Encryptor{
private static String key="asdfghjklqwe@321" ;
private static String initVector = "RandomInitVector";

public static void encryptFile(File inputFile, String outputFolderPath) {
    try {
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey,new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8")));

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        File encryptedFile = new File(outputFolderPath,inputFile.getName());
        encryptedFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        encryptedFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("File encryption completed successfully.");
        inputFile.delete();
        System.out.println("File deleted from the original location.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have one JAR file which calls this method (which implements a Timer).The code of the class file inside JAR

```
public class encryptFiles extends TimerTask {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        encryptFiles mainObj = new encryptFiles();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mainObj, new Date(), 3600000L);
    } catch (Exception ae) {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run(){
File ipath = new File(INPUT);
File[] listOfFilesClient = ipath.listFiles();
for (File fileToBeProcessed : listOfFilesClient)
{
  try
  {

      Encryptor.encryptFiles(fileToBeProcessed,OUTPUT);  

  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}

}
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: address
at java.net.InetAddress.init(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress.<clinit>(InetAddress.java:271)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.getSystemEntropy(JarVerifier.java:783)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.testSignatures(JarVerifier.java:706)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.access$400(JarVerifier.java:34)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$1.run(JarVerifier.java:183)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$1.run(JarVerifier.java:149)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.<clinit>(JarVerifier.java:148)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:318)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:263)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:48)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:78)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:76)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:499)
at org.excel.encryptor.Encryptor.encryptFile(Encryptor.java:42)
```

Both the class files are kept in different JAR files in different packages. Everything works fine if runs in Windows Machine.(Java 1.7_70), but fails in Solaris(Java 1.7_72 32). So, what may be the reason for this Exception ? Why it is happening only in Solaris? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If any further information required please ask me in comment section.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094259/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-in-solaris-while-using-cipher-getinstance-but-works (but no answer) I also found this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3631773 (but useless IMHO)